# Trigger not firing on GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I made a custom variable that returns true when the element I want is in the page.
And I made a custom trigger that when this variable equals true it will fire the trigger.
In preview mode I checked in the variables tab and the variable value is true, but the trigger is not firing...
So I know the problem is in the trigger? Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

[image: My Variable]

[image: My Trigger]

Answer (score 1):

Unless your dataLayer also contains a key "event" with the value "Busca" this will not fire (since you are using a trigger that looks for that custom event).

Use a Pageview trigger instead (or a Dom Ready if your variable ist set after the GTM code is loaded), together with your condition.